# Links in Y-Axis of stacked bar chart

Tags: highcharts, hyperlink

I am a total newbie to Highcharts and especially to Javascript. I wonder how to put hyperlinks behind the labels on the y-axis. So far I could not find an answer, neither in the docs nor here. I have something like this:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    colors: ['#c83f3f', '#66b257'],    
    fontFamily: 'Merriweather Sans, sans-serif',
        xAxis: {
        categories: ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Test 4', 'Test 5', 'Test 6', 'Test 7', 'Test 8']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Nicht erfüllte Kriterien',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 6, 4, 5]
    }, {
        name: 'Erfüllte Kriterien',
        data: [5, 7, 6, 3, 8, 4, 6, 5]
    }]
});
```

Now I would like to put links to external sites behind the "Test 2", "Test 2" etc. labels. - How would I do that?

Thank you very much!
-Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give `anchor<a>` tags in the `categories` array of `xAxis`. With specifying the link in it.like this:

```
     categories: ['<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Test 2',
 '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions">Test 5</a>']
```

**Sample code:** I have given links to Test 2 and Test 5 in this sample:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    colors: ['#c83f3f', '#66b257'],    
    fontFamily: 'Merriweather Sans, sans-serif',
        xAxis: {
        categories: ['Test 1', '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Test 4', '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions">Test 5</a>', 'Test 6', 'Test 7', 'Test 8']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Nicht erfüllte Kriterien',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 6, 4, 5]
    }, {
        name: 'Erfüllte Kriterien',
        data: [5, 7, 6, 3, 8, 4, 6, 5]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```